LinkedList detect node where cycle starts
all. I hope you are doing great. I am trying to do an alternative approach to the tortoise and hare algorithm to detect when the cycle starts in a linked list. I am trying to mark nodes as visited by having their next pointers mark to a temporary node. However, my approach only passes half the test cases. Can someone please tell me what is wrong, and if the idea would work at all? Thanks. Assume my Node class only has attributes data and next which default to None.
    @staticmethod
    def get_node_start_cycle(root):
        curr = root
        tmp_node = Node(-1)
        while curr.next:
            if curr.next == tmp_node:
                return curr
            tmp_next = curr.next
            curr.next = tmp_node
            curr = tmp_next
        return -1


Not sure how equality is defined for Nodes.  Are you sure there's not a Node(-1) already in the linked list?  What happens if you replace == with is?

It seems that this approach is going to permanently alter the list.  That isn't something you'd normally want to do.  Are you sure it's allowed by this specific problem?

It is inconsistent that your function either returns -1 or a node instance. I would expect either (1) the return value should be None or a node instance, or (2) the return value should be -1 or a valid index (or node value) in the original linked list. What is the exact description of the code challenge?
